# Tao Framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Возникла проблема при добавлении компонента SimpleOpenGLControl...

После установки TaoFramework добавил к SolutionExplorer три dll-ки:

1. Tao.OpenGl;
2. Tao.FreeGlut;
3. Tao.Platform.Windows;

Нужный контрол лежит в Tao.Platform.Windows. Затем правым кликом в тулбоксе выбираю "Choose Items".

И в списке контрола SimpleOpenGLControl нет... Как решить проблему?

**Добавление.**

Да, ссылки добавил...

[image]

Comment: @Антон Ногин Правильно редактировать вопрос, дополняя его по мере необходимости, вместо создания уточняющих ответов: это соответствует формату форума "вопрос - ответы".

Answer (score 1):

В ссылках все правильно!

В коде добавляем:

```
using Tao.FreeGlut;
using Tao.OpenGl;
using Tao.Platform.Windows;
```

Затем поступаем так:

```
namespace ololo  
{  
    public partial class Form1 : Form  
    {  
        void initgraphics()  
        {  
            SimpleOpenGlControl sm = new SimpleOpenGlControl();  
        }  
        ...  
    }  
}
```

пруфлинк - http://members.hellug.gr/nkour/Tao.OpenGL_Builder/SimpleIntro_Borland.html

Answer (score 0):

Если вы просто положили длл в проект, то ничего и не появится. Надо добавить в проект ссылки на библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

В висуал-басике это будет так:

```
Imports Tao.FreeGlut
Imports Tao.OpenGl
Imports Tao.Platform.Windows
```